# Stripe Laravel not getting some params from Checkout Form

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason, some parameters such as amount, and description are not being passed on from the Form to the Controller.

The token is generated and the email is sent too, but not the other params.

In order for the Payment to work I have to enter manually the amount at the controller.

```
<form action="checkout" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key= "pk_test_zOi8g9ztDo1HNeC6iFFTWqwk"
    data-amount="1500"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 shoes ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

=====================================

```
 public function PostPaymentData(){


        Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_CvCavCI3G4onNbKxZEaNzkvZ');

        // get the data submitted by the CHECK OUT Form

        $token  = Input::get('stripeToken');  (it gets it)
        $amount = Input::get('amount');      (it does not get it)
        $description = Input::get('description');(it does not get it)
        echo "the amount is . $amount";  //nothing
        echo "the description is  $description";    // nothing

        print_r(input::all());  // it just prints the token and the email 

      // create the charge on STRIPE servers. This will charge the credit card

      try {
            $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 1800, // amount in cents, again  (I have to enter it manually because $amount = ' ';
            "currency" => "usd",
            "card" => $token,
            "description" => "holycow@gmail.com")
              );
          }
        catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
            // Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught

            dd($e);
```

=================================================

```
Route::get('payments/getpaymentpage', array(
    'as'=>'getpaymentpage',
    'uses'=>'StripePay@getPaymentPage'

));


Route::post('payments/checkout', array(
    'as'=>'checkout',
    'uses'=>'StripePay@PostPaymentData'

));
```

My config for Stripe:

In the providers:

```
'Abodeo\LaravelStripe\LaravelStripeServiceProvider'
```

In the composer json

```
"stripe/stripe-php": "1.*",
        "abodeo/laravel-stripe": "dev-master"
```

Comment: Well, first inspect the resulting DOM when stripe's script has finished executing. May be there is no resulting parameters left in the form after it.

Comment: I dont quite understand how you mean.., I have checked in Firebug NET ALL and it reads Status: aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was the support staff from Stripe (very kind people) who has given me the answer:

It's actually expected that the amount doesn't get sent with the token to your server. If it did, the user could easily tamper with it via developer tools or writing javascript snippets, etc. Usually you'll want the price of something to be in your database somewhere (a product or whatever you're selling) and look it up again once you receive the token to get the authoritative price.

But sometimes you've got a situation where the user specifies the price somehow, and that is intentional. In that case I suggest making a hidden form element:

And then populating that with JavaScript using a callback. If you're using Stripe.js you already have a response handler you can use for this, just populate the field before you POST your data. If you're using Stripe Checkout, then you can use the `token` callback on the handler using the custom integration.